# Nested linked list C

Tags: c

I need to create linked list inside linked list in C.

```
struct subject                  
{
char *subj[100];
char *tutor[100];
char *mark[10];
char *date[20];

struct subject* next2;
}*head2;

struct student            
{
char *name[20];
char *surname[20];
int num;
struct subject *head2;

struct student* next1;
}*head1;
```

I have these two structures. I try to add new node like this in loop using file.

```
 void newstudent(FILE *fp, char buffor[255], char buffor1[255])
 {
 struct student *temp1;
 temp1 = (struct student*) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
 struct subject *temp2;
 temp2 = (struct subject*) malloc(sizeof(struct subject));
 fscanf(fp, "%s", temp1->name);
 fscanf(fp, "%s", temp1->surname);
 fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp1->num);
 strcpy(temp2->subj, buffor);
 strcpy(temp2->tutor, buffor1);
 fscanf(fp, "%s", temp2->mark);
 fscanf(fp, "%s", temp2->date);
 temp1->next1 = NULL;
 head1 = temp1;
 temp2->next2 = NULL;
 head2 = temp2;
 }
```

And when I need only to add subject.

```
struct subject *temp2;
temp2 = (struct subject*) malloc(sizeof(struct subject));
strcpy(temp2->subj, buffor);
strcpy(temp2->tutor, buffor1);
printf("%s %s\n",temp2->subj,temp2->tutor);
fscanf(fp, "%s", temp2->mark);
fscanf(fp, "%s", temp2->date);
temp2->next2 = head2;
head2 = temp2;
```

I have problem, when I try to display elements from "subject" list.

```
while(link != NULL)
{

    fprintf(output, "%s %s\n", link->name,link->surname);
    fprintf(output, "Number: %d\n", link->num);
    struct subject *link2 = head2;
    while (link2 != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%s\n", link2->subj);
    }

    link = link->next1;
}
```

I think this is problem with implementation nested list.

Comment: Undefined behavior galore. Turn on compiler warnings, read them, fix them, try again.

Comment: Does the student really have an array of 20 first name pointers and second name pointers? Or did you intend `char name[20];` instead of `char *name[20];`? Similar with the other structures. Why oh why did you not experiment on a simple case, and build the code step by tiny provable step?

Answer (score 1):

The loop:

```
while (link2 != NULL)
{
    fprintf(output, "%s\n", link2->subj);
}
```

Will be infinite if link2 is not null. Inside the loop there *must* be a statement that assigns NULL at some point, to make the loop finish.